# When primary/foreign key is based on more than one column breeze client mix data after save

Tags: breeze

I got some problems when the primary/foreign key is based on more than one column in the table.
Everything is ok when saving after creating a new object but when the client side updates its fk_data after save, breeze is mixing the key columns.
This is resulting in wrong data in the key columns and breeze thinks something is modified again.

It all happens here breeze.debug.js:

```
 // update fk data property - this can only occur if this navProperty has
        // a corresponding fk on this entity.
        if (property.relatedDataProperties) {
            if (!entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
                var inverseKeyProps = property.entityType.keyProperties;
                inverseKeyProps.forEach(function(keyProp, i ) {
                    var relatedDataProp = property.relatedDataProperties[i];
                    // Do not trash related property if it is part of that entity's key
                    if (newValue || !relatedDataProp.isPartOfKey) {
                        var relatedValue = newValue ? newValue.getProperty(keyProp.name) : relatedDataProp.defaultValue;
                        that.setProperty(relatedDataProp.name, relatedValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The inverseKeyProps don't match with the correct relatedDataProp.

Is this a bug in breeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with order of the fk_keys in the edmx file.
Why the order differs from the database i don't now.

TJ